# В чем подвох? А?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Прохожу сейчас книгу "Разработка игр на unity 2018 за 24 часа". Одно из практических заданий:
Сейчас мы создадим интерактивное приложение, в котором используется движение и триггеры. Упражнение требует, чтобы вы творчески подошли к поиску решения (потому что здесь оно не представлено). Если вы оказались в тупике и нуждаетесь в помощи, вы можете обратиться к файлам примеров для часа 9.

1. Создайте новый проект или сцену. Добавьте на сцену куб и поместите его
   в позицию с координатами (–1,5, 0, –5). Задайте кубу масштаб (0,1, 2, 2)
   и присвойте ему имя LTrigger.
2. Продублируйте куб (щелкнув правой кнопкой мыши по кубу на панели
   Hierarchy и выбрав команду Duplicate). Назовите новый куб RTrigger
   и поместите его в позицию с координатами (1,5, 0, –5).
3. Добавьте на сцену сферу и поместите ее в позицию с координатами (0, 0, –5).
   Добавьте в сферу компонент Rigidbody и сбросьте флажок Use Gravity.
4. Создайте скрипт под названием TriggerScript и прикрепите его к объектам
   LTrigger и RTrigger. Создайте скрипт под названием MotionScript и прикрепите его к сферe
5. 5. Теперь начинается самое интересное. Вам нужно создать в игре следующие
      функциональные возможности.
       Игрок должен иметь возможность перемещать сферу с помощью клавиш со стрелками.
       Когда сфера входит в один из триггеров, покидает его или остается
      в нем, в консоль должно выводиться соответствующее сообщение: имя
      триггера (LTrigger или RTrigger) и тип взаимодействия (вход, выход,
      нахождение внутри).
       В этом упражнении есть небольшой подвох, который вам придется
      преодолеть, чтобы справиться с задачей

Сделал все по инструкции, [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
public class MovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update ()
    {
        float mX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") / 10f;
        float mY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") / 10f;
        transform.Translate(mX, mY, 0);
    }
}



 public class TriggerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        print(gameObject.name + " enter");
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        print(gameObject.name + " stay");
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        print(gameObject.name + " exit");
    }
}
```

Так вот, сфера просто проходит через триггеры и им вообще все равно. Я мог бы скипнуть данное упражнения, но ответа в интернете нет, а в решениях к задаче код аналогичный.Это уже дело принципа, может знает кто в чем тут дело?

Comment: могу предположить что используются функции 2д, в то время как обьекты 3д. Соответственно и коллайдеры используются 3д, а ты ищешь 2д коллайдеры.

Comment: Подвох под юбкой у трапа. А название вопроса должно содержать суть проблемы.

Comment: _Разработка игр на unity 2018 за 24 часа_ - это ловушка. Без базовых знаний C# вы ничему не научитесь, ни за 24 часа, не за 24 дня. А загвоздка как раз в них, вот для разминки https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ Нужно хотя-бы базовое понимание ООП.

Answer (score 1):

Вот начало решения. Дальше сам пропиши OnTriggerStay и т.д

```
public class TriggerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string myName;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        myName = gameObject.name;
    }


    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other) { print(myName + " Enter"); }
    }
}
```